# Firestore: traer el ultimo ID de un documento

Tags: firebase, firestore

Buen dia, en vista que no veo como hacer un autoincrement automatico en firebase en cuanto al ID del documento (cosa que no entiendo por que no se puede cuando es muy util a la hora de trabajar por ejemplo pedidos, los cuales llevan un consecutivo), me veo en la obligación de consultar el ultimo para luego sumarle +1

tengo la consulta así:

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "viajes"), orderBy("numero", "desc"), limit(1));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {                             
    console.log(doc.id);
  });
```

tengo tres viajes de id 1, 2 y 3

asi quite o ponga orderBy("numero", "desc") y limit(1), me sigue mostrando 1 2 3, no se que estaré haciendo mal, error no da como tal, solo que no limita ni ordena

Alguna idea?

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero ayudarte los Query puede usarse para ordenar una colección de datos
basada en algunos atributos, así como restringida a la gran lista de elementos. (para datos de chat similares) hasta un número adecuado para sincronizar con él cliente. Para más información:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

De todas manera te dejé el ejemplo resuelto espero que sea lo que buscaba pero
es muy bueno revise la  documentación

```
const q = query(
  collection(db, "viajes"),
  limit(1),
  orderBy("numero", "desc"),
);

const el = await getDocs(q);

const product = el.docs.map((doc) => ({
  id: doc.id,
  ...doc.data(),
}));
```

Comment: gracias Jackson, justo lo que necesitaba, no me funcionó con la documentación pero si con la modificacion que pusiste aquí, muy amable!

Comment: @GabrielUribeGomez aunque seas el autor de la pregunta, debe ser el autor de la respuesta quien modifique el código. En lugar de editar su respuesta, debes sugerirle en un comentario lo que debe modificar.

Comment: @padaleiana bien, entendido

Comment: de nada me alegra que te sirvió, saludos